# Merge the two xml fragments into one?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, xquery

How to merge the xml content of `@a` and `@b` into `@c`?

```
declare @a xml = (select 1 aaa for xml path('AAAs'));
declare @b xml = (select 1 bb1, 2 bb2 for xml path('BBBs'));
declare @c xml = ... @a + @b ....?
```

I need to pass the merged xml to a stored procedure.

---

I know it's possible to cast the xml to varchar and concat them and convert it back to xml. Any better approach? The xml content can be big.

Comment: I would try to just query the XML variables using `for xml`. I'm not at a computer right now but something like this could work. `select @a as A, @b as B for xml path('root')`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, I found one way

```
select @a, @b for xml path ('')
```