# SQL Server FOR XML PATH: Set xml-declaration or processing instruction "xml-stylesheet" on top

Tags: sql-server, xml, for-xml-path, processing-instruction, xml-declaration

I want to set a processing instruction to include a stylesheet on top of an XML:

The same issue was with the xml-declaration (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`)

**Desired result:**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<TestPath>
  <Test>Test</Test>
  <SomeMore>SomeMore</SomeMore>
</TestPath>
```

My research brought me to **node test** syntax and `processing-instruction()`.

This

```
SELECT 'type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"' AS [processing-instruction(xml-stylesheet)]
      ,'Test' AS Test
      ,'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
FOR XML PATH('TestPath')
```

produces this:

```
<TestPath>
  <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
  <Test>Test</Test>
  <SomeMore>SomeMore</SomeMore>
</TestPath>
```

All hints I found tell me to convert the XML to VARCHAR, concatenate it "manually" and convert it back to XML. But this is - how to say - ugly?

This works obviously:

```
SELECT CAST(
'<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<TestPath>
  <Test>Test</Test>
  <SomeMore>SomeMore</SomeMore>
</TestPath>' AS XML);
```

Is there a chance to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another way, which will need two steps but don't need you to treat the XML as string anywhere in the process :

```
declare @result XML =
(
    SELECT 
        'Test' AS Test,
        'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
    FOR XML PATH('TestPath')
)
set @result.modify('
    insert <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
    before /*[1]
')
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4628)</kbd>**

The XQuery expression passed to `modify()` function tells SQL Server to insert the processing instruction node before the root element of the XML.

**UPDATE :**

Found another alternative based on the following thread : [Merge the two xml fragments into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9778390/merge-the-two-xml-fragments-into-one) . I personally prefer this way :

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, '<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>'),
(
    SELECT 
        'Test' AS Test,
        'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
    FOR XML PATH('TestPath')
)
FOR XML PATH('')
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/4630)</kbd>**

Comment: Great input, thank you! Until they find something like `top-processing-instruction()` this is a very good work around!

Comment: Hi har07, I just had to deal with adding the xml-declaration and thought, this could be done similarly, but it did not. I added an answer with the (pretty obvious) solution...

Answer (score 0):

As it came out, har07's great answer does not work with an XML-declaration. The only way I could find was this:

```
DECLARE @ExistingXML XML=
(
    SELECT 
        'Test' AS Test,
        'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
    FOR XML PATH('TestPath'),TYPE
);

DECLARE @XmlWithDeclaration NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT N'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
           +
           CAST(@ExistingXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
);
SELECT @XmlWithDeclaration;
```

You must stay in the `string` line after this step, any conversion to *real XML* will either give an error (when the encoding is other then `UTF-16`) or will omit this xml-declaration.