# SQL appending <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> to Query output

Tags: sql-server, xml, encoding, utf-8

So i'm having a bit of trouble to figure out how i could make this work
so that i can append the xml encoding 
to my query.

this is what i hacked together so far:

```
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @SQLCmd   VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT  @FileName = 'C:\SampleXMLOutput.xml'

-- in this command, we are making sure there is only one ROOT node


SELECT @SQLCmd = + 'bcp ' + 
                         '"SELECT Id, Initials, firstname, lastname, email ' +
                         ' FROM Employees.dbo.IDCards ' +
                         ' FOR XML PATH(''Employee''), ELEMENTS,  ROOT(''Employees''), TYPE "' +
                         ' queryout '  +
                   @FileName +
                   ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME



-- display command, for visual  check
SELECT @SQLCmd AS 'Command to execute'

-- create the XML file
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @SQLCmd
```

Also i need to get some data from another table within the same query output.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server FOR XML PATH: Set processing instruction "xml-stylesheet" on top](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806454/sql-server-for-xml-path-set-processing-instruction-xml-stylesheet-on-top)

Comment: I doubt this is correctly tagged. Does MySQL support `FOR XML PATH` ???. The given syntax and the `bcp` points to SQL Server...

Comment: it's for SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume - due to the syntax - that you are using SQL Server...

With `FOR XML PATH` it is possible to create a `processing instruction` like this

```
SELECT 'test' AS OneNormalElement
      ,'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"' AS [processing-instruction(abc)]
FOR XML PATH('Test')
```

The result

```
<Test>
  <OneNormalElement>test</OneNormalElement>
  <?abc version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
</Test>
```

But you are not allowed to use `AS [processing-instruction(xml)]`. You get the error:

> Error: 6879, Severity: 16, ‘xml’ is an invalid XML processing
>   instruction target. Possible attempt to construct XML declaration
>   using XML processing instruction constructor. XML declaration
>   construction with FOR XML is not supported.

It is actually **not supported to create any PI outside** of your XML...

The question I've linked as "duplicate" shows some workarounds how to add this anyhow...

### UPDATE

I must apologize for the late response as well as for the wrong hint. The xml-declaration is handled differently, so the linked answer did not help actually. I updated this also...

The only way I found to add an XML-declaration is `string concatenation`:

```
DECLARE @ExistingXML XML=
(
    SELECT 
        'Test' AS Test,
        'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
    FOR XML PATH('TestPath'),TYPE
);

DECLARE @XmlWithDeclaration NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
           +
           CAST(@ExistingXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
);
SELECT @XmlWithDeclaration;
```

And if you want to do it in one single call, you must do this without `,TPYE`

```
DECLARE @XmlWithDeclaration NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
    SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'
           +
            (
            SELECT 
                'Test' AS Test,
                'SomeMore' AS SomeMore
            FOR XML PATH('TestPath')
            )
);
SELECT @XmlWithDeclaration;
```

So - finally - I hope this is your solution:

#### Edit: doubled quotes. See comments.

```
SELECT @SQLCmd = + 'bcp ' + 
                     '"SELECT ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>'' + ' + 
                     ' (SELECT Id, Initials, firstname, lastname, email ' +
                     '  FROM Employees.dbo.IDCards ' +
                     '  FOR XML PATH(''Employee''), ELEMENTS,  ROOT(''Employees'')) "' +
                     ' queryout '  +
               @FileName +
               ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Wouldn't your example add the encodig to every element ?

I only want it appended in the beginning.

How would it look in the code i pasted?

Comment: @user6381438 did you read the link I posted below your question as possible duplicate?

Comment: Yes i looked at the link but i'm not sure how to go about it with the code i already put together?

Comment: First of all, no need to apologize for the late response and the hint. I  really appreciate the time you've spent just trying to be helpful :)
@Shnugo 

Thanks Shnugo ! that seemed to do the trick.. almost :)

The hyphens are not carried over in the output.
so instead of <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
output is <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>

Comment: Hi @user6381438, according to [this](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1500518-392-1.aspx) BCP wants the inner double quotes doubled: `<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>`

Comment: Hmm i'm pretty sure i tried that and they were not there.

Tried again and they sure indeed are where they should be ;)

Again thanks a bunch for your time!!

Comment: I've been trying to SELECT from multiple tables, but i can only get it to work with CROSS JOIN.

Comment: Sorry i tried to edit the comment, but i was to late, and the rest of the code i thought i had pasted didn't show.
I've Created a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785553/select-from-multiple-tables-without-iteration) - Hoped you would have the time to have a look at it since you helped with the other issue :)

Comment: Had to create a new question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785553/select-from-multiple-tables-without-iteration)