# SELECT from multiple tables without iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Trying to SELECT from Multiple tables into 1 query output.
Only getting it to work with CROSS JOIN, the output though is not what i'm trying to achieve. It seems to iterate the query per COLUMN from the other table.

```
SELECT @SQLCmd = + 'bcp ' + 
                 '"SELECT ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>'' + ' + 
                 ' (SELECT ValID, ValSet, Id, Initials, firstname, lastname, email ' +
                 '  FROM Employees.dbo.IDCards CROSS JOIN Employees.dbo.Value' + 
                 ' WHERE CardID = 0 ' +
                 ' AND Value = 1 ' +
                 '  FOR XML PATH(''Employee''), ELEMENTS,  ROOT(''Employees'')) "' +
                 ' queryout '  +
           @FileName +
           ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```

The output comes out like this.

```
- <Employees>
-   <Employee>
      <ValID>1</ValID> 
      <ValSet>Beach</ValSet>
      <id>4</id> 
      <Initials>JJ</Initials> 
      <Firstname>Jack</Firstname>
      <Lastname>Jack</Lastname>
      <email>JJ@testserver.com</email> 
    </Employee>
-   <Employee>
      <ValID>2</ValID> 
      <ValSet>Forrest</ValSet>
      <id>4</id> 
      <Initials>JJ</Initials> 
      <Firstname>Jack</Firstname>
      <Lastname>Jack</Lastname>
      <email>JJ@testserver.com</email> 
    </Employee>
- </Employees>
```

So how would one SELECT from multiple tables without it iterating?

**UPDATE**
I've been trying som different things.
But this is how it looks now added another table.

```
IDCards

Id  | Initials  | firstname | lastname  | email
4   | JJ        | Jack      | Jack      | JJ@testserver.com
5   | MM        | Mike      | Mike      | MM@testserver.com

Value

ValID   |   ValSet  |
1       | Beach     |
2       | Forrest   |

CardData

CardID  | CardVal   |
4       | 1         |
5       | 1         |
5       | 2         |
```

I need it to run once per user if that  makes sense?

Comment: Cross join will give you the cartesian product. Take a look at Inner Joins, or Left Joins if you're not always going to have matching data.

Comment: @Rich - i've tried but it won't run with either... Probably because i'm doing it wrong.

Comment: you can do but in that case xml objects (node /tree) in doc will have issue..

Comment: @sandeeprawat Not sure i understand?

Comment: @ jjonson  then what u need ..

Comment: @sandeeprawat I need it not to iterate the selected objects from Employees.dbo.Value and only return the specific object i need.

Comment: What is the content of `dbo.IDCards` and what is in `dbo.Value`? Might be you need a `JOIN`?

Comment: @Shnugo - I've updated the question with contents of the tables.

Comment: @JJonson, But in your query you filter on `WHERE CardID=0`. This column is part of table `CardData` which is not part of your query? And there is no CardID with 0? How are the tables related? Is it: `JJ has one card (Nr 1) and MM has two cards (1 and 2)`? Please define the expected output fitting to the given data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit clears some details, but it is still quite foggy :-)

The only relation I can imagine (due to the given values) was this. Is this correct?

```
DECLARE @IDCards TABLE(Id INT,Initials VARCHAR(100),firstname VARCHAR(100),lastname VARCHAR(100),email VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @IDCards VALUES
 (4,'JJ','Jack','Jack','JJ@testserver.com')
,(5,'MM','Mike','Mike','MM@testserver.com');

DECLARE @Value TABLE(ValID INT, ValSet VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Value VALUES
 (1,'Beach')
,(2,'Forrest');

DECLARE @CardData TABLE(CardID INT, CardVal INT);
INSERT INTO @CardData VALUES
 (4,1)
,(5,1)
,(5,2);

SELECT *
FROM @Value AS v
INNER JOIN @CardData AS cd ON v.ValID=cd.CardVal
INNER JOIN @IDCards AS ic ON cd.CardID=ic.Id
```

This is the result:

```
+-------+---------+--------+---------+----+----------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| ValID | ValSet  | CardID | CardVal | Id | Initials | firstname | lastname | email             |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+----+----------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| 1     | Beach   | 4      | 1       | 4  | JJ       | Jack      | Jack     | JJ@testserver.com |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+----+----------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| 1     | Beach   | 5      | 1       | 5  | MM       | Mike      | Mike     | MM@testserver.com |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+----+----------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
| 2     | Forrest | 5      | 2       | 5  | MM       | Mike      | Mike     | MM@testserver.com |
+-------+---------+--------+---------+----+----------+-----------+----------+-------------------+
```

If this is correct you might look for a query like this:

```
SELECT Id
      ,Initials
      ,firstname
      ,lastname
      ,email  
      ,(
        SELECT ValID
              ,ValSet
        FROM @CardData AS cd 
        INNER JOIN @Value AS v On cd.CardVal=v.ValID
        WHERE cd.CardID=ic.Id
        FOR XML PATH('Card'),TYPE
       )
FROM @IDCards AS ic
FOR XML PATH('Employee'),ROOT('Employees')
```

As the cards are `1:n` you need to put them within a sub-select
This was the result (fishing in very dirty water...):

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Id>4</Id>
    <Initials>JJ</Initials>
    <firstname>Jack</firstname>
    <lastname>Jack</lastname>
    <email>JJ@testserver.com</email>
    <Card>
      <ValID>1</ValID>
      <ValSet>Beach</ValSet>
    </Card>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <Id>5</Id>
    <Initials>MM</Initials>
    <firstname>Mike</firstname>
    <lastname>Mike</lastname>
    <email>MM@testserver.com</email>
    <Card>
      <ValID>1</ValID>
      <ValSet>Beach</ValSet>
    </Card>
    <Card>
      <ValID>2</ValID>
      <ValSet>Forrest</ValSet>
    </Card>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Comment: the output is exactly what i'm looking for, but i'm getting an error when trying to run the query.

Must declare the table variable "@CardData".

Comment: @JJonson Just remove the @ Use your actual table names

Comment: really appreciate your help you're awesome!

Not sure why i got the errors yesterday... Tried with the actual tablenames again and it worked. 

Having issues when i try in conjunction with bcp
I've updated the question and the tables that i'm trying it with. 

Runs fine without the nested SELECT.

Comment: @JJonson One principle of Stack Overflow is: One issue - one question. The issue here is *How do I get the correct output?*. This is solved. Please mark my answer as accepted and - if not done yet - vote it up. Then place a new question. This has several advantages: New questions pull the most attraction. Following researches have a better chance to find the correct answer for their issues. Points on my account (and yours!), and the chance for even more points with the second question. Thx Please place a link here to relate your questions and I will pop up there soon...

Comment: Wasn't aware of this principle :)
But you're correct that the question was answered And Here's the new [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855004/nested-inner-join-with-bcp)

Answer (score 0):

Use a UNION clause.

```
SELECT columns FROM table1
UNION
SELECT columns FROM table2
```

The queries must have the same number of columns

Comment: And if they don't have the same number of columns?

Comment: If you are trying to SELECT from Multiple tables into 1 query output then they must have the same number of columns.