# Nested INNER JOIN with bcp

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, bcp

So this query works fine without the nested SELECT/INNER JOIN.
Not sure what is wrong with the nested SELECT, any ideas?

So can't seem to get it to work in conjunction with bcp

```
SELECT @SQLCmd = + 'bcp ' + 
                         '"SELECT ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>'' + ' + 

                         ' (SELECT CardId, Initials, firstname, lastname ' +
                         '      (SELECT CardId, SetVal ' +
                         '      FROM Business_data as bd ' +
                         '      INNER JOIN Business_set as bs on bd.SetVal=bs.id ' +
                         '      WHERE bd.CardID=ic.CardID ' +
                         '      FOR XML PATH(''BD''), TYPE ' +
                         '      ) ' +
                         ' FROM IndexCards as ic' + 
                         ' FOR XML PATH(''Employee''), ELEMENTS,  ROOT(''Employees'')) "' +
                         ' queryout '  +
                   @FileName +
                   ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```

These are the tables that i'm using

```
Indexcards

CardId  | Initials  | firstname | lastname  |
1       | AH        | Ash       | Hart      |
2       | AL        | Alex      | Lang      |

Business_set

ID  | Val     |
1   | Media   |
2   | Tech    |

Business_data

CardId  | SetVal  | 
1       | 1       |
2       | 1       |
2       | 2       |
```

Comment: Do you miss a comma after 'lastname' in the nested SELECT query.

Comment: @DaniMathew No i don't believe i do, it's the nested SELECT that is giving me trouble

Comment: @JJonson, questions along the lines of "why my code is not working?" are not allowed in SO. Read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Regarding the actual question: have you tried to debug it? By "debug it" I mean split it into smaller components to try and narrow down the problem. I would start by extracting the query that builds XML and then run it on its own to see if an error could be there.

Comment: @Alex - Fair enough - I've tried getting it to work but as i wrote, the nested SELECT/INNER is the thing giving me trouble the rest works fine.

Comment: @JJonson, debugging dynamic SQL statements is basically guess work, which can be eliminated by trying to run individual commands as plain (non dynamic) SQL. Additionally you did not specify if the query produces any errors or just "not works".

Comment: @Alex - Error i get when using the example Dani made below is _Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The multi-part identifier "bd.SetVal" could not be bound.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'CardId'._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your last question I take, that this is in database **Employees.dbo**. I think, that you should either fully qualify all your table's names of - better - place an `USE Employees;` before your select.

And I think, that Dani Mathew is right, that there is a comma missing. The sub-select is - seen form the main select - just a *column* to inlcude in the output.

Try it like this:

```
SELECT @SQLCmd = + 'bcp ' + 
                        '"USE Employees; SELECT ''<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>'' + ' + 

                        ' (SELECT CardId, Initials, firstname, lastname, ' +
                        '      (SELECT CardId, SetVal ' +
                        '      FROM dbo.Business_data as bd ' +
                        '      INNER JOIN dbo.Business_set as bs on bd.SetVal=bs.id ' +
                        '      WHERE bd.CardID=ic.CardID ' +
                        '      FOR XML PATH(''BD''), TYPE ' +
                        '      ) ' +
                        ' FROM dbo.IndexCards as ic' + 
                        ' FOR XML PATH(''Employee''), ELEMENTS,  ROOT(''Employees'')) "' +
                        ' queryout '  +
                @FileName +
                ' -w -T -S' + @@SERVERNAME
```

Comment: Awesome stuff! I had to go with the fully qualified table names, not sure why USE didn't work. Thanks a bunch!