# NameSpaces in xml sql

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, xml-namespaces

How can I declare the namespaces in a query?

I get an error when declaring the namespaces

```
Declare @Mydoc xml
set @Mydoc = (
         select importe, algo,XD,
               (select impuesto,tasa,transferencia
                from CfdiDet
                for xml raw('cfdi_detalle'),type)
         from cfdienc
         for xml raw('cfdi_encabezado'),type)
```

This is the part where I have a problem

```
set @Mydoc.modify('declare xmlnamespaces ('uri',cfdi')
```

I want to replace the `"_"` with `":"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefixes are not just a part of string you could manipulate with a `.modify()`... Well, you *could* convert the XML to string, do a `REPLACE` and convert it back to XML. But the proper way is to declare the namespace.

To declare a namespace you can either use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` or use an implicit namespace declaration (not possible in your case).

Try this

```
DECLARE @Mydoc XML;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('uri' AS cfdi)
SELECT @Mydoc=
(
SELECT 'SomeDummy' AS importe
FOR XML RAW('cfdi:encabezado'),TYPE
);

SELECT @Mydoc
```

The result

```
<cfdi:encabezado xmlns:cfdi="uri" importe="SomeDummy" />
```

Comment: do you happen to know how I'm doing the encoding = "uft-8" to my file? is that it is only generated in version = "1.0" and now ...

Comment: you are my hero!! :D

Comment: @carlitus212 The XML declaration `<?xml ...blah ...?>` is not really bound to the XML. This is something which tells a consumer details about the content and it's encoding. There is absolutely no sense in writing something like `utf-8` into the header, if the real encoding is `UCS-2`. This declaration is not just some fancy magic... When you write your XML to a file, you should set the proper encoding and state this in the header. This **is not supported** natively. [Read this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37439159/5089204)

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot :D

Comment: hello friend, I wanted to see if you could just help me one more time, how could replace the "cfdi_" with "cfdi:" without using a namespaces since it duplicates for each node and does not work for me

Comment: @carlitus212 just use something like `REPLACE(CAST(YourXml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'cfdi_','cfdi:')`. And use another `REPLACE()` or `STUFF()` to set the namespace declaration into the root node manually.