# SQL - cast XML as nvarchar(max)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've got a problem with an `SQL` `stored procedure`.
I need to generate a `xml` from a database. 
In my stored procedure, I collect all information and then my plan was to generate the XML file as I need it (see code).

All transactions I need to report are loaded into the variable `@transactionXml`. It is of data type `xml` and can become quite big.

```
SET @xmlOut += '<export_datuma>' + cast(CAST(getdate() as date) as nvarchar(100)) + '</export_datuma>'
SET @xmlOut += '<export_szla_db>' + @noOfResults + '</export_szla_db>'
SET @xmlOut += '<kezdo_ido>' + cast(@fromDate as nvarchar(max)) + '</kezdo_ido>'
SET @xmlOut += '<zaro_ido>' + cast(@toDate as nvarchar(max)) + '</zaro_ido>'
SET @xmlOut += '<kezdo_szla_szam>' + @minInvoiceNo + '</kezdo_szla_szam>'
SET @xmlOut += '<zaro_szla_szam>' + @maxInvoiceNo + '</zaro_szla_szam>'
SET @xmlOut += cast(@transactionXml as nvarchar(max))
SET @xmlOut += '</szamlak>'

SELECT @xmlOut
```

When I try to cast the datatype to `nvarchar(max)` (as in the code section), the string is not complete and missing some information. It seems, that the string is cut after x-signs.

Is there a way to cast the `@transactionXml` variable completely to text, so that I can use it in my `@xmlOut` statement?

Comment: How are you verifying that the string is "not complete"? If you are outputting to Management Studio, it is simply truncating the string for presentation.

Comment: Is it really? This was my hint, that the string(xml) is not complete.

Comment: By "how" I meant *where*. If in Management Studio, it's not the string's fault, it's the tool's. I wrote about this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

Comment: There is a closing `</szamlak>` without the opening tag? Did you miss to copy the first line or is it really missing?

Comment: You should **not create an XML on string level!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create an XML on string level! Try this:

```
SELECT CAST(getdate() as date) AS export_datuma
      ,@noOfResults AS export_szla_db
      ,@fromDate AS kezdo_ido
      ,@toDate AS zaro_ido
      ,@minInvoiceNo AS kezdo_szla_szam
      ,@maxInvoiceNo AS zaro_szla_szam
      ,@transactionXml AS [*] --This is the pre-created XML which should be fine
FOR XML PATH('szamlak');
```

The pre-created XML must be fine, otherwise you could not store it as XML native type.

Creating the XML on string level can have various dangerous side effects. Just imagine a forbidden character within one of your variables...

Comment: That's a really good solution. Thanks very much! Is there also a way to include before the data `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`?`

Comment: @dns_nx [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37477855/5089204). In short: The XML's declaration is **never** part of a *native-type-XML* within SQL Server. It is a hint about the encoding of a file. SQL-Server's XML is encoded `UTF-16 / UCS-2` in any case. A differing declaration would be wrong. You can add any string fragment after a `CAST` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, but be sure to store this as `UTF-8` encoded file, if you write this into the declaration. Many people take this declaration just as some *fancy extra*...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the quick info.